# Finding polynomial roots by attempts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I barely remember that I could identify them by attempts. I would get the coefficient, see what numbers can divide it and put them into the Ruffini's rule.

But I don't even know what such method is called.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme  maybe?

Comment: Perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem?

Comment: Rational Root Theorem, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Yuval.

Comment: Do you still need the algorithm of how to find these or your question is answered?

Answer (score 4):

The OP was after the [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

(Added so the question could be officially answered.)